# How do I uninstall XP Mode in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, uninstall

I installed Windows XP Mode on a Windows 7 64-bit machine. However, the virtual machine update won't install so I cannot run XP Mode. At this point I decided to abandon the installation.

I can't find XP Mode in the Control Panel, making it impossible to remove that way. What other way can it be uninstalled?

Comment: What edition of Windows 7 is this?  Which "Update" is it you are referring to?  What happens when you try to run the update?  Does XP Mode show up in your list of Virtual PCs?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the download required to install the virtual PC, not an update to this. When I try to install virtual PC, I get the helpful message that it is impossible to install. It's Windows 7 Professional service pack 1. XP Mode doesn't show up anywhere except in the list of programmes.

Comment: OK, so you are using a valid edition of 7, are oyu sure you got the 64-bit XP mode installers? What's the actual error message you get? What do you mean by it shows up in the list of programmes?  Which list of programs?

Comment: By list of programmes I mean C:\\programmes\xpmode. I downloaded the virtual PC install again and this time it went OK. However this has not resolved the problem. Virtual PC and XP mode appear in the programme list on the start menu but clicking XP mode brings up the invitation to download and install XP mode. Virtual PC appears in the list of Windows options which are uninstallable but xp mode does not. Trying to download XP mode again does not work: the download simply won't start.